# elisp に定番のテストフレームワークはありますか

Tags: emacs, elisp

ruby には rspec, javascript (nodejs) には jest といった、単体テスト用のフレームワークで、定番の物があるかと思います。

emacs の elisp は書いていくと普通に高度なプログラムを書くことになるかと思いますが、であるならばテストフレームワークがほしくなるな、と思いました。

## 質問

elisp (パッケージ) の開発において、定番のテストフレームワークはありますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacsには標準で、ertというものが付属しているので、これを使うプロジェクトは多いようです。  
詳細な利用方法も標準マニュアルに記載されています。

- [ERT: Emacs Lisp Regression Testing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ert/index.html)

```
(ert-deftest 1=1 ()
  (should (= 1 1)))


(ert '1=1)                              ;M-x ert(ret)1=1

Selector: 1=1
Passed:  1
Failed:  0
Skipped: 0
Total:   1/1

Started at:   2020-05-17 20:11:08+0900
Finished.
Finished at:  2020-05-17 20:11:08+0900

.
```